# hide an iframe in ie8

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

How do hide an iframe in ie8?

This is not working.

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; border: 0px; " id="_iframe" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `iframe` has a closing tag, i.e.

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; border: 0px; " id="_iframe"></iframe>
```

You've used it like a single tag, i.e.

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" ... />
```

This is not valid for iframe and this could be a problem for `IE` because it's not smarter like other browsers.

Comment: thanks, i made the update still have the same issue. When i post to this iframe i get a new tab in ie8. I want to hide window or a really small window instead of the full window i get in ie8.

Comment: What is about post ? Did I missed anything, can you tell me more. Also, only `style="display:none"` is enough.

Comment: sorry, i am posting to this iframe.  the iframe is hidden on load but once i post to it.  ie8 opens the iframe window in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the name attr to the iframe.

ie

```
<iframe height="0" name="iframe" width="0" ... />
```